# Plyr based on which.min for hole data.frame with colwise not working

Tags: r, plyr

Hello I have a list `re` where the elements contain dataframes with the colnames: c(values, diff, Sample1, Sample2, Sample3,...) up to Sample 100-1000.

The column "values" has not unique values and the column diff represents the difference from another vector (which is not included in the data.frames).

so exemplatory I got for the first important two columns:

```
values<- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4)
diff  <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1)
```

Now I want (for every dataframe in the list) to reduce the dataset, that only one element of unique `values` is left with the smallest value in diff. So in the upper case:
values=c(1,2,3,4)
diff<-c(1,1,1,1)

I tried plyr:

```
for (k in 1:length(re)) {
    ret[[k]] <- ddply(re[[k]], .(valueData), summarise, re[[k]][which.min(diff),]) }
```

giving the Error:

```
Error in vector(type, length) : 
  vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'closure'.
```

because I have not only the columns "values" and "diff" in the data.frames but many more with differencing sizes I cant just name every column :

```
ret[[k]] <- ddply(re[[k]], .(valueData), summarise, diff=min(diff), 
                      Sample1=Sample1[which.min(diff)],Sample2=Sample2[which.min(diff)],Samplex...)
```

So how could I fix this or is there another option despite plyr?

Any ideas?
And many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(re,function(df){
  df <- df[order(df$values,df$diff),]
  df[!duplicated(df$values),]
})
```

Just sort your dataframe in a ascending manner and pick the first unique value in `values` column.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this asap. But is there no direct way with plyr?

Comment: `ret[[k]] <- ddply(ret[[k]], .(values),function(df)df[which.min(df$diff),] )` will do it. `summarise` means to add new columns, and it is not needed here.